# inputing string value in function in vue template string

Tags: string, templates, vue.js

I am learning Vue and try to create a call to an onclickfunction with a string argument. But it seems that i cant use single ' or double " quotationmarks. and the escape way /' or /" doesnt work either. is there a way to accomplish this without putting the name in to the data section of the vue component? The output would change from: *Hey there i am Gandalfion.*  to *Hey there i am nameinstringformat.*  when the button of the component was clicked if everything would work.

```
Vue.component('greeting',{
template:"<p>Hey there i am {{name}}.<button v- 
on:click='changeName("nameinstringformat")'>Change name!</button></p>"
  ,
data : function(){
  return{
    name: 'Gandalfion'

  }
},
methods: {
  changeName: function(namein){
    this.name=namein
  }
}
```

//this doesnt work

```
Vue.component('greeting',{
template:"<p>Hey there i am {{name}}.<button v-on:click='changeName(name2)'>Change name!</button></p>"
  ,
data : function(){
  return{
    name: 'Gandalfion',
    name2: 'Leif2'
  }  
},
methods: {
  changeName: function(namein){
    this.name=namein
  }
}
//this workaround works
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "/" to escape quotation marks? I yes then you should use "\" (backslash) :)

So this should work:

```
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: "<p>Hey there i am {{name}}.<button v-on:click='changeName(\"nameinstringformat\")'>Change name!</button></p>",
  data: function() {
    return{
      name: 'Gandalfion'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeName: function(namein) {
      this.name = namein
    }
}
```

P.S. even if you're just learning, please start paying attention to the code format and spacing.

Comment: It worked as well as @skirtles answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of ways this could be escaped to get it to work. As with all escaping the key is to understand exactly why something needs escaping and to employ the appropriate escape sequence.

Using `\"` should work fine as the double quotes are just clashing with the template string's delimiters. Other similar escape sequences, such as `\u0022` should also work.

In your example you're using single quotes around the attribute value, so to use single quotes within the inline listener you'd need to escape them using an HTML entity. e.g. `&#39;`. You could do something similar to get double quotes working too.

This is one reason for using Vue SFCs, because it helps to avoid all the string escaping problems by not using a JavaScript string to specify the template.

When specifying a template as a string the usual convention is to use backticks for the template string's delimiters, double quotes for attribute values and single quotes for strings within those values. e.g.:

```
template: `
  <p>
    Hey there i am {{name}}.
    <button v-on:click="changeName('nameinstringformat')">
      Change name!
    </button>
  </p>
`
```

Most of the time that avoids any clashes in the first place. Using backticks has the added advantage that the string can span multiple lines.

This example illustrates both `\"` and `&#39;`:

```js
Vue.component('greeting', {
  template: "<p>Hey there i am {{name}}.<button @click='changeName(\"nameinstringformat\")'>Change name!</button><button @click='changeName(&#39;nameinstringformat2&#39;)'>Change name!</button></p>",
  data () {
    return {
      name: 'Gandalfion'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeName (namein) {
      this.name = namein
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <greeting></greeting>
</div>
```

Comment: Good to know about best practice with the backticks, thanks!